# JWS transport best practices

Tags: node.js, jwt, json-web-signature

I have a JWS, the payload contains just regular data.
My question is there is a right way to send this JWS in a body in a post request ?
I mean there is special headers or something else about JWS transport.
My body is just:

```
{
  jws: "regular.jws.signature.here"
}
```

Comment: *the payload contains just regular data* - are you refering to the payload of the JWS or the request payload? It sounds like you mean the JWS payload, so does it mean you don't use the JWS for authorization but to transport signed data?

Comment: Yes, I want to transport only signed data